# Change select value when changing another select

Tags: php, jquery, html, checkbox

I got 3 array's where from i make 2 select box and a checkbox. What i want to do is that when i change CMS the checkbox value needs to change like in the array.

if i choose Joomla in the select box then i want the checkbox that is made with the `$aOnderdelen`, then in the array `$aOnderdelen` i have an array with Contact-form Foto-gallery and Carousel and this 3 have an array with the name of each CMS with different values and this are the values that the checkbox needs to get when you choose one of those and the CMS.

Example: i choose Joomla and i choose a Contact-formulier than contact-formulier checbox gets 3 as value.

```
$aCMS = array('SilverbeeCMS','Joomla','WP','Drupal','Scott');

$prijsPerUur=1;
$basisPrijs=
array(
    array('titel' => 'Kopie', 'uur' => '8'),
    array('titel' => 'Maatwerk', 'uur' => '10'),
    array('titel' => 'Aangekocht', 'uur' => '12'),
    array('titel' => 'Custom', 'uur' => '14')
     );

$aOnderdelen = array
(
    'Contact-formulier' => array 
        (
            'SilverbeeCMS'=>3,
            'WP'=>2,
            'Joomla'=>3,
            'Drupal'=>4,
            'Scott'=> 5
        ),
    'Foto-gallery' => array
        (
            'SilverbeeCMS'=>1,
            'WP' => 3,
            'Joomla'=> 4,
            'Drupal'=> 5,
            'Scott'=> 6
        ),
    'Carousel' => array
        (
            'SilverbeeCMS'=>1,
            'WP' => 4,
            'Joomla'=> 5,
            'Drupal'=> 6,
            'Scott'=> 7
        )
);

    ?>
```

This is the HTML form where the Select and checkbox are

```
<form action="" method="post">
   <select id="cms" class="form-control" name="cms">
      <?php foreach($aCMS as $key => $value): ?>
      <option value="<?php echo strtolower($aCMS[$key]); ?>"> 
      <?php echo $aCMS[$key]; ?>
      </option>
      <?php endforeach; ?>                          
   </select>    

  <label><?php echo $template.$verplicht; ?></label>

  <select id="templates" class="form-control" name="templates">
      <?php foreach($basisPrijs as $key => $value): ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $basisPrijs[$key]["uur"]; ?>">
      <?php echo $basisPrijs[$key]["titel"]; ?>
      </option>
      <?php endforeach; ?>                          
  </select>    

  <?php echo $oTitel; ?>
  <div class="checkbox col-xs-12">
     <div class="row">
        <?php foreach($aCMS as $cmsKey => $cmsValue) ?>            
        <?php foreach($aOnderdelen as $key => $value):
            foreach($value as $key1 => $value1)
              {};
              $i++;
              echo "<div class='checkbox'>
        <label><input class='check".$i."' type='checkbox' value='".strtolower($key)."'  name='".$key."'>".$key."</label></div>"
                    ;endforeach;?> 

      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You need to do this with either JS or AJAX

Comment: What would you recommend

Comment: That's entirely up to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New Answer more Flexibel
First Loop through the PHP array.

```
 <?PHP
    foreach($aCMS as $cmsKey => $cmsValue)
 ?>
 <?php
    foreach($aOnderdelen as $key => $value)
      :
       foreach($value as $key1 => $value1){};
  ?>
```

Than use data attr to get the prices.

```
<input class="<?php echo strtolower($key);?>" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo strtolower($key)?>" name="<?php echo $key;?>" data-silverbeecms="<?php echo $value['SilverbeeCMS']; ?>" data-wp="<?php echo $value['WP'];?>" data-joomla="<?php echo $value['Joomla'];?>" data-drupal="<?php echo $value['Drupal'];?>" data-scott="<?php echo $value['Scott'];?>">
```

After you get the Price in the data you can call this data from JQUERY and do the Match.

```
urenOnderdelen = 0;  
    $("#sCms, #templates, .contact-formulier, .foto-gallery, .carousel").change(function() 
        {
            urenOnderdelen = 0;   
            urenTemplate = $("#templates").val();
            $(".contact-formulier, .foto-gallery, .carousel").each(function()
            {
                if(this.checked) 
                {
                    urenOnderdelen+=parseInt($(this).data($("option:selected").val())); 
                }  
            });  
            $("#output, #output1, #gVoor").hide().fadeIn(300);
            urenTemplate = $("#templates").val();  
            urenTemplate = parseInt(urenTemplate); 
            urenOnderdelen = parseInt(urenOnderdelen);
            totaal = urenOnderdelen + urenTemplate;
            $("#output").text(euroTeken + totaal*prijs);
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use jquery along with AJAX for changing things dynamically

Simple example as

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#selector').change(function() {
        //do here things required about changing
        //You can also change DOM elements according to needs
        //and have Ajax requests
    })
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I found how to do it

```
switch($("option:selected").val()) 
                 {
                 case "silverbeecms":
                         $(".check1").val(<?php echo $aOnderdelen["Contact-formulier"]["SilverbeeCMS"] ?>)
                         $(".check2").val(<?php echo $aOnderdelen["Foto-gallery"]["SilverbeeCMS"] ?>)
                         $(".check3").val(<?php echo $aOnderdelen["Carousel"]["SilverbeeCMS"] ?>)
                         break;

                case "joomla":
                         $(".check1").val(<?php echo $aOnderdelen["Contact-formulier"]["Joomla"] ?>)
                         $(".check2").val(<?php echo $aOnderdelen["Foto-gallery"]["Joomla"] ?>)
                         $(".check3").val(<?php echo $aOnderdelen["Carousel"]["Joomla"] ?>)
                         break;

                case "wp":
                         $(".check1").val(<?php echo $aOnderdelen["Contact-formulier"]["WP"] ?>)
                         $(".check2").val(<?php echo $aOnderdelen["Foto-gallery"]["WP"] ?>)
                         $(".check3").val(<?php echo $aOnderdelen["Carousel"]["WP"] ?>)
                         break;

                case "drupal":
                         $(".check1").val(<?php echo $aOnderdelen["Contact-formulier"]["Drupal"] ?>)
                         $(".check2").val(<?php echo $aOnderdelen["Foto-gallery"]["Drupal"] ?>)
                         $(".check3").val(<?php echo $aOnderdelen["Carousel"]["Drupal"] ?>)
                         break;

                case "scott":
                         $(".check1").val(<?php echo $aOnderdelen["Contact-formulier"]["Scott"] ?>)
                         $(".check2").val(<?php echo $aOnderdelen["Foto-gallery"]["Scott"] ?>)
                         $(".check3").val(<?php echo $aOnderdelen["Carousel"]["Scott"] ?>)
                         break;
                 }
```